# useState does not give the expected result

Tags: reactjs

I have a get request in react application
I get the values from that request using: `const dataFromReq = selector.data;`

 When i make:   `console.log(dataFromReq)`, in my component i get all values. But, i want to set the `dataFromReq` to another state. For this i made: `const [anotherState, setAnotherState] = useState(dataFromReq)`, and now i expect when i will do: `console.log(anotherState)`, to display my values, but it does not work and i get an empty array.
I know that `useState` is asynchronous but, how to get the value in `console.log(anotherState)`?

Comment: Can you show more code instead of single lines

Comment: The initial state is set once, not every time the value changes. That's what the setter is for.  When you get the data from the request, do `setAnotherState(selector.data)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `useEffect` to update some state

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selector && selector.data) {
      setAnotherState(selector.data)
    }
  }, [selector]);
}
```